# Proving that a polynomial about the volume of a tetrahedron is irreducible

Tags: polynomials, polyhedra, irreducible-polynomials

We know that the volume of a tetrahedron $ABCD$ can be represented as
$$144V^2=(a^2b^2d^2+b^2c^2e^2+c^2a^2f^2+b^2a^2e^2+c^2b^2f^2+a^2c^2d^2+c^2e^2f^2+a^2f^2d^2+b^2d^2e^2+c^2d^2f^2+a^2e^2d^2+b^2f^2e^2)-(a^2b^2c^2+a^2e^2f^2+b^2f^2d^2+c^2d^2e^2)$$
where $a=BC, b=CA, c=AB, d=AD, e=BD, f=CD$.

Let $F(a,b,c,d,e,f)$ be the right hand side of the above equation. Then, here is my question.

> **Question** : Is $F(a,b,c,d,e,f)$ irreducible as a polynomial?

The answer must be YES, but I don't know how to prove that. Can anyone help?

Comment: you can see:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice there are no linear terms in $a$. So it is a polynomial of the form $Aa^2+B$. So, $B/A$ must be a square.

$A=b^2(d^2+e^2+f^2e^2+c^2)+(e^2f^2+c^2f^2+c^2d^2+f^2d^2+c^2d^2f^2+e^2d^2)$

and

$B=b^2(f^2d^2+c^2e^2+c^2f^2+d^2e^2)+(c^2d^2e^2+c^2e^2f^2)$

if I didn't miss some term.

Check that $A$ and $B$ don't have a common factor, which I haven't done. And then it is clear they are not squares themselves, since they have no terms linear in $b$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't know if your answer is right, which does not mean that your answer is wrong. I suspect we need to prove that $A$ is irreducible as a polynomial in order to say "$B/A$ must be a square." I hope I'm not mistaken. By the way, some signs have to be changed.

Comment: Assume $Aa^2+B=(C_1a+D_1)(C_2a+D_2)=C_1C_2a^2+(C_1D_2+C_2D_1)a+D_1D_2$. So, $C_1D_2=-C_2D_1$. Then $B/A=(D_1D_2)/(C_1C_2)=-(D_1/C_1)^2=(iD_1/C_1)^2$. The thing that is needed is then to show that $B$ and $A$ done have a common factor to then imply that each $A$ and $B$ must be a square.

Comment: To show that $A$ and $B$ dont have a common factor you could show they dont even factor. Each $A$ and $B$ are also of the form $Cb^2+D$. So, after showing that $C$ and $D$ dont have a common factor, then $D$ and $C$ must be a squares. ... Eventually you get to consider polynomials with few variables, like $d^2+c^2$, which factors but doesnt have common factors to $e^2+1$ and both are not squares.

Comment: Thanks. I understood your idea. I'll try by myself.